# How to to read a matrix from a given file?

Tags: python, file-io

I have a text file which contains matrix of N * M dimensions.

For example the input.txt file contains the following:

```
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,2,1,0,2,0,0,0,0
0,0,2,1,1,2,2,0,0,1
0,0,1,2,2,1,1,0,0,2
1,0,1,1,1,2,1,0,2,1
```

I need to write python script where in I can import the matrix.

My current python script is:

```
f = open ( 'input.txt' , 'r')
l = []
l = [ line.split() for line in f]
print l
```

the output list comes like this

```
[['0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0'], ['0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0'], ['0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0'],
 ['0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0'], ['0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0'], ['0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0'],
 ['0,0,2,1,0,2,0,0,0,0'], ['0,0,2,1,1,2,2,0,0,1'], ['0,0,1,2,2,1,1,0,0,2'],
 ['1,0,1,1,1,2,1,0,2,1']]
```

I need to fetch the values in int form . If I try to type cast, it throws errors.

Comment: Are you sure your input file looks like that? Why does it have the blank lines between the matrix rows? You should get empty lists in your matrix with your current code. If I remove those, I get `[['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1'],...` so something seems odd with your output.

Comment: Yes, McGwyne that output isnt for the matrix i showed as an example. I will edit the input . Also there are no blank lines between the rows. I am trying to make the input look like a matrix .

Comment: You should provide the input *exactly* as you have it, not in some other representation. Otherwise you will just confuse people, and we have no way of knowing what is going wrong with your program.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Consider

```python
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    l = [[int(num) for num in line.split(',')] for line in f]
print(l)
```

produces

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1]]
```

Note that you have to split on commas.

---

If you do have blank lines then change

```
l = [[int(num) for num in line.split(',')] for line in f ]
```

to

```
l = [[int(num) for num in line.split(',')] for line in f if line.strip() != "" ]
```

Comment: I am getting this error 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0'

Comment: @MGwynne: s/he needs to split on commas... use `line.split(',')`

Comment: @6502 Ah, s/he has edited it. It didn't have them originally.

Answer (score 23):

You can simply use [numpy.loadtxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html).
Easy to use, and you can also specify your delimiter, datatypes etc.

specifically, all you need to do is this:

```
import numpy as np
input = np.loadtxt("input.txt", dtype='i', delimiter=',')
print(input)
```

And the output would be:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 2 1 0 2 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 2 1 1 2 2 0 0 1]
 [0 0 1 2 2 1 1 0 0 2]
 [1 0 1 1 1 2 1 0 2 1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
fin = open('input.txt','r')
a=[]
for line in fin.readlines():
    a.append( [ int (x) for x in line.split(',') ] )
```

Answer (score 1):

The following does what you want:

```
l = []
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
  for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    if len(line) > 0:
      l.append(map(int, line.split(',')))
print l
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not write your csv parser, consider  the `csv` module when reading such files and use the `with` statement to close after reading:

```
import csv

with open('input.txt') ad f:
    data = [map(int, row) for row in csv.reader(f)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this small one line code for reading matrix,

```
matrix = [[input() for x in range(3)] for y in range(3)]
```

this code will read matrix of order 3*3.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
f = open ( 'input.txt' , 'r')
l = []
l = np.array([ line.split() for line in f])
print (l)
type(l)
```

output:

> ```
> [['0']  ['0']  ['0']  ['0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0'] 
>     ['0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0'] 
> ['0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0']]
> ```
>
> numpy.ndarray

Answer (score 1):

The following code converts the above input to matrix form:

```
f = open ('input.txt' , 'r')
l = []
l = [line.split() for line in f]
l=np.array(l)
l=l.astype(np.int)
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you for this. Please note the code is now `l=l.astype(np.int32)  # or np.int64`

Comment: The code can be condensed to:
`f=open ('input.txt' , 'r')` and next line `l=np.array([line.split() for line in f]).astype(np.int32)`