# How to construct matrix form txt file?

Tags: python

I am now working with some output matrix from analysis program
I received the output matrix in the form of txt file (which is huge). Now I need to read this file using Python and convert this data to matrix.

This is a small example of the data output:

```
[   1,   1]: 1.410e+010 [   1,   2]: 0.000e+000 [   1,   3]: 0.000e+000 [   1,   4]: 3.561e+009 [   1,   5]: 0.000e+000 [   2, 1]: 0.000e+000 [   2,   2]: 1.460e+009 [   2,   3]:-8.903e+007 [   2,   4]: 2.671e+007 [   2,  5]: 4.630e+009 [   3,  1]: 0.000e+000 [   3,  2]: 1.068e+008 [   3,  3]: 7.123e+009 [   3,  4]: 0.000e+000 [   3,  5]: 0.000e+000 [   4,  1]: 2.386e+009 [   4,  2]: 0.000e+000 [   4,  3]: 0.000e+000 [   4,  4]: 5.876e+008 [   4,  5]: 2.226e+008 [   5,  1]: 2.226e+008 [   5,  2]: 2.920e+009 [   5,  3]: 0.000e+000 [   5,  4]:-1.781e+008 [  5,  5]:-2.920e+009
```

as shown, the location index of each matrix value is located before it.

Comment: where is your attempt at solving it?

Comment: So? What is your question? What is the problem you are facing? Seems rather straight forward to parse the indexes and assign them the values. What did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions with a straight-forward pattern matching the data format, and the [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) function:

```py
import re

with open("test.txt") as file:
    data = file.read()

for entry in re.findall(r'\[\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\s*\]: ([0-9e+.]+)', data):
    print(entry)
```

This will give:

```
('1', '1', '1.410e+010')
('1', '2', '0.000e+000')
('1', '3', '0.000e+000')
('1', '4', '3.561e+009')
('1', '5', '0.000e+000')
('2', '1', '0.000e+000')
# etc.
```

So now you can use it to set an empty matrix:

```py
import re

n = 5
mat = [[0 for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]

with open("test.txt") as file:
    data = file.read()

for x, y, value in re.findall(r'\[\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\s*\]: ([0-9e+.]+)', data):
    mat[int(x)-1][int(y)-1] = float(value)  # indexes are 0-based

print(mat)
```

Which will give:

```
[[14100000000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3561000000.0, 0.0], 
 [0.0, 1460000000.0, 0, 26710000.0, 4630000000.0], 
 [0.0, 106800000.0, 7123000000.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
 [2386000000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 587600000.0, 222600000.0], 
 [222600000.0, 2920000000.0, 0.0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: awesome, i think it is good solution. but still a small problem, the given example is very small one with known dimensions. in the real application it will be huge one (may be up to 10 million) with unknown dimensions . So, do you think if i let  'n=len entry' would it work . another question is it possible to write this matrix to txt file in pure form of just rows and column of numbers without  parentheses?

Comment: Regarding your last question, see [How to write a matrix/ 2D-array to a text file python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60692703/6045800) and [How to to read a matrix from a given file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7618858/6045800) to see how to simply write and read the matrix as a table. Regarding your first question - if your matrix is always square, i.e. nXn, you can check the size of the first row (i.e. how many entries with the same row) and apply that as `n`.